# Delete, Insert, Update using table from cache?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which runs a couple of deletes, inserts and updates for several tables.

My problem: The procedure causes key constraint violations.

Example:

```
DELETE FROM tableA WHERE key='1'
DELETE FROM tableB WHERE key='1'
```

Table B has a foreign key reference to table A, the procedure stops and I get an error message. All changes are discarded.

My question: How can I tell the procedure or server that the entry in table A is already deleted? Can I use table A from the cache for the foreign key reference comparisons?

I use a microsoft sql server.

*EDIT*

I'm sorry, I mixed the chronological order.
In fact, table A has the FK and its entry is the first one to be deleted. 
Table B follows afterwards with no reference to table A. 
Nevertheless, I get a "conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint" message.
The only explanation for this error message I have is, that the delete on table A is not committed.

*EDIT*
I may have found the problem. All my delete statements are enclosed in BEGIN/END.

So I have:

```
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM tableA WHERE key='1'
  DELETE FROM tableB WHERE key='1'
END
```

As far as I understand, such enclosed statements are run as one big statement before anything is committed.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. To perform queries in the correct so the server will be able to execute them correctly.
2. You can get rid of foreign keys for those tables during the execution of the procedure.

Comment: @1 Do you mean correct order? They are in the correct order. Shouldn't I get an error msg then?

Comment: He means you must delete the table with the foreign key reference first (tableB) and then tableA. Switch your statement.

Comment: Or third option, create the FK with CASCADE, example here http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2743/using-delete-cascade-option-for-foreign-keys/.

Answer (score 0):

If `TABLEB` has a FK from `TABLEA` then you must first delete from`TABLEB`:

```
DELETE FROM tableB WHERE key='1'   --Doing this will remove the row that references TABLEA
DELETE FROM tableA WHERE key='1'   --TABLEA can be deleted because there are no references to the row in the other TABLE
```